Variable is never used and Empty 'catch' block - unused variable
My code contains unused variables and empty 'catch' blocks.
During static code analysis with my IDE and SonarQube, it was flagged that variable 'a' is never used, and there are empty 'catch' blocks.
These findings have resulted in a poor SonarQube score. So what I can do for  improve code readability and/or fix issues without change the code's logic? How to declare unused variables correctly?
I aim to enhance the readability of my code and/or achieve better results in SonarQube reports.
...
catch (StatementNotFoundException e) { } //Unused variable
...


almost never a good idea to write an empty catch block... (unless in some {older} unit tests)

I agree with you, but with a lot of legacy code or some more "interesting" solutions, I wanted to know how to technically show the analysis tools that this is what I'm aiming for and it's not a bug. There are also cases when an exception is simply needed, due to an already used older implementation. But I agree with you

AFAIK SonarQube also has provision to turn warnings off using comments...

Yes, in certain cases like an empty constructor or another body

Underscore character (_)
Unnamed variables and patterns, introduced as a preview feature in Java 21, have now transitioned into a finalized feature in Java 22 per JEP 456.
Denoted by the underscore character _ (LOW LINE, Unicode code point 95 decimal), these unnamed patterns and variables enhance code clarity and maintainability while reducing the likelihood of errors.
LinkedList<Integer> intLink = ...
while (intLink.size() >= i) {
   var x = link.remove();
   var _ = link.remove(); // Underscore character  _
   ... new Coordinate(x) ...
}

Naming ignore (ignore)
If you're intentionally using an empty catch block to ignore exceptions, it's still important to follow clean coding practices. Using a variable name like ignore instead of a typical descriptive name signals to other developers that the exception is intentionally ignored, reducing confusion and making the code more readable.
This will remove SonarQube warnings about unused variables
...
catch (StatementNotFoundException ignore) { //variable ignore
       //Nothing 
} 
...


why not just link.remove(); // no var ? (such a Déjà vu... {feels like I have asked something like that before...}

Right, but I wanted to show what the documentation might look like and how static code analysis tools might identify it as a normal occurrence. I can change the example probably

But the “empty 'catch' blocks” issue is still unsolved.

I don't see a problem in either IJ or SQ reports when I started using "ignore" among others. IJ itself suggests doing so as a recommendation - "ignore".
When you do "ignore" it knows that your body can be empty because you don't use a value

Of course, you can choose to ignore warnings. Or you can just not use these tools in the first place. However, you decided to post a question about both SonarQube warnings and your answer doesn’t address your own question.

But the SQ plugin in IJ understands, by "ignore", that the block is empty and this did not happen by chance, because this is the desired action.

@deikyb why not use catch (StatementNotFoundException _) { }? Unnamed variables are intended to be used for unused catch clause variables too.

You can, but only from Java 22
